# Height not rendering correctly at certain times

Tags: jquery, css, html, anythingslider

The first time you load and visit some of the slides on this page http://www.blythestoves.co.uk/new the correct height doesn't render. Some information is cut off. Go to slide 2 (Ecomaster BB1) and under the images of the air flow dials there should be some info on the warranty. The page doesn't render that last text block.

Here is the weird part. If you refresh the page nothing happens but if you go to the address bar and click in there and push return again the page will load correctly with the height all correct.

I really don't understand and have spent too much time on this already. Any help would be really great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that webkit browsers fire off the document ready event before the images start loading and thus the image dimensions have not been obtained. So if you include the image dimensions in the css or inline:

```
<img src="images/blythe-ecomaster-bb2.jpg" style="width:1228px;height:678px;" />
```

then the slider height will be appropriately sized.

Additionally, the width option in the slider initialization has been deprecated, so you can only set the slider dimensions using css. So you can remove this line, because it doesn't do anything:

```
width : 1228,          // Override the default CSS width
```

Comment: That certainly fixed the issue. Thanks fudgey. For final fixed result see blythestoves.com

Answer (score 1):

Without isolating in a fiddle I can't tell for sure, but I'd guess it's not resizing because you explicitly told it not to with `resizeContents : false`:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
                                width : 1228,          // Override the default CSS width
                                resizeContents : false,
                                navigationFormatter : formatText,
                                autoPlay : false,
                                easing: 'easeInOutExpo'

                        });
```

Get that out of there and it may work. If not, set us up a fiddle ;)

Comment: `resizeContents : false`

Is a little misleading. That actually auto-resizes the content, without that I would have to set a height over the slides overall.

Which would make the smaller slides look odd giving lots of white space at the bottom.

Comment: The `resizeContents` option will add `width:100%;height:100%` to the immediate solitary child inside of a slide (i.e. the first element it finds, if it is the only immediate element); so a div wrapping an image and caption will get that css applied, but not the image or caption. A slide with only an image or an iframe/embedded video will get that css applied and resize to fit the slide dimensions. If there are more than one elements immediately inside the slide, then it won't do anything to the elements. Whew.. I hope that was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on firefox and chrome? It might be an overflow css problem is it only appears in IE.

Andrew

Comment: So you can see the two columns of text, under images of the Air-flow controls?

It works for me in Firefox, but chrome has the same issue as I am having in Safari. Maybe its something to do with Webkit.